# Aligning image with text, without lowering text

Tags: html, css, image

So I have a "post" box, and that will contain an avatar and the post. The issue is when I add an image the text drops below the image. Here's what I'm talking about [image]

All I want to do is align the picture with the text. Here's my code for the image

```
cursor: default;
height: 74px;
width: 74px;
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
margin-right: 19px;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: -19px;
display: inline-block;
```

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/37r5g/2/) a demo. Its not the most complete demo, but it works. Any help would be nice.  I'm trying to align the text with the image

Comment: Demo is incomplete with invalid HTML and the image appears oddly positioned. At least an image of how it's **supposed** to look would be of some use.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/37r5g/5/)?

Comment: Yes.  I just need to align the text with the image now @TylerH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could float your image to the left.

```
img { 
    float: left;
}
```

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/37r5g/3/)

or you could position absolutely (might be more appropriate).

```
.post {
    position: relative; /*Make absolutely positioned children relative to their .post parents */
}

.post img { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -37px; /* negative. half of height/*
}
```

This will keep your image in the center of the post.

[Have a second fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/37r5g/6/)

Comment: Well how would I align the text with the image then? Like vertically align.

Comment: Yes. How do you fix that?

Comment: `top: 50%` and the negative top margin keep the image centered in the post.

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
float:left;
```

Here is a JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UWtEF/

hope that helps

Comment: please demonstrate how this would help in a JSfiddle.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say that this answers my question, because it doesn't align the image with the text....

Comment: What do you mean by align? I thought that it meant side by side

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and if I understand your problem, you want text align on the right of avatar.
Actually you know the avatar size then the most simple solution is first to create context for position, then :

```
.post{position:relative;/* your other properties here */}
```

now you have a context, you can add absolute for your avatar like :

```
#IMG_1{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;/* your other properties here, don't forget to remove margins */}
/* I suggest you to replace #IMG_1 by .post > img{} */
```

now you need only to add padding-left inside your block content for post then :

```
.post{padding-left:84px;/* your other properties here and don't forget position:relative; */}
```

Now you need only to correct others selectors like .message, .likes, .time to remove paddings (padding-left in .post is enough).

I hope this help you.